# Find time it took to run a cron job?

Tags: cron, time

Normally I don't post questions which are trying to get advice on how to directly a question in a textbook but in this case I feel it is necessary.

The last questions said to write a C program and then set it up as a cron job. I've done that.

The next question asks *(so I assume it's possible)*:

> Explain how you can find the time it took the computer to execute your
>   program.

Half the time I'm not sure if the program even executed at all so I'm glad to hear there may be a method to not only check that but how long it took to execute.

How can I find the time taken to execute the program?

Comment: use the time command

Comment: @Ijax Would I add that to the cron job command?

Comment: yes , time the command and redirect the timing info to some file on disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like it's asking for the time it took to execute your C program, not how long cron took to execute it. However, as others have commented, you can use the `time` program to time a command's execution, as below:

`$ time myprogram` will give you the total time the program took to execute to completion.